# How to properly set Passkeys for Django?

Tags: python, django, passkey

I'm trying to apply Passkeys to a Django project, but I'm new to both and am finding difficulties.

So following instructions I found [here](https://github.com/mkalioby/django-passkeys) on how to add Passkeys I'm supposed to the following code to my `settings.py` file:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = \['passkeys.backend.PasskeyModelBackend'\] # Change your authentication backend
FIDO_SERVER_ID="localhost"      # Server rp id for FIDO2, it the full domain of your project
FIDO_SERVER_NAME="MTGStore"
import passkeys
KEY_ATTACHMENT = NONE | passkeys.Attachment.CROSS_PLATFORM | passkeys.Attachment.PLATFORM
```

`NONE` is not a keyword in Python though, so I've tried using `None` but that gave me a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'AuthenticatorAttachment'` error.

Also thought I am using `localhost` for my server ID, I'm not sure what to add for my authentication backend.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `None` for `KEY_ATTACHMENT` at all. Based on what you need for your project for the `KEY_ATTACHMENT` config in your `settings.py` module, you should have sth like below configs:

```py
KEY_ATTACHMENT = passkeys.Attachment.PLATFORM
```

or

```py
KEY_ATTACHMENT = passkeys.Attachment.CROSS_PLATFORM
```

Also, you can see this config in the example project [here](https://github.com/mkalioby/django-passkeys/blob/7ea85cc2efe3ce7a7ab217c3276ab55af9b6dabb/example/example/settings.py#L135) in [django-passkeys](https://github.com/mkalioby/django-passkeys) project.

In addition based on this [import](https://github.com/mkalioby/django-passkeys/blob/7ea85cc2efe3ce7a7ab217c3276ab55af9b6dabb/passkeys/__init__.py#L1) in this project, if you see
[**`AuthenticatorAttachment`** <sup>[python-fido2
]</sup>](https://github.com/Yubico/python-fido2/blob/d52024ebef06124d9c3ed4cdd373e2e836f3c0f5/fido2/webauthn.py#L441) object you'll find out you have just two above configs for this setting.